# Tcl/Tk: using array with expr

Tags: arrays, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am running into problems while trying to access `array` inside an `expr`. The code which reproduces the error is shown below which is adapted from Donal Fellows answer to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796800/how-to-implement-a-button-whose-functionality-is-a-cross-between-radiobutton-and/6799235#6799235).

```tcl
namespace eval Ns {
}

proc Ns::main_routine {} {
  global cb

  array set cb {
    c1 0
    c2 0
    c3 0
    c4 0
  }

  checkbutton .c1 -text "C1" -variable     cb(c1)
  checkbutton .c2 -text "C2" -variable     cb(c2)
  checkbutton .c3 -text "C3" -variable     cb(c3)
  checkbutton .c4 -text "C4" -variable     cb(c4)

  grid .c1 -sticky w
  grid .c2 -sticky w
  grid .c3 -sticky w
  grid .c4 -sticky w

  # _After_ initializing the state...
  trace add variable cb(c1) write Ns::reconfigureButtons
  trace add variable cb(c2) write Ns::reconfigureButtons
  trace add variable cb(c3) write Ns::reconfigureButtons
  trace add variable cb(c4) write Ns::reconfigureButtons
}

proc Ns::reconfigureButtons args {
  global cb

  # this one works
  set state "normal"
  if { $cb(c1) } {
    set state "disabled"
  }
  .c2 configure -state $state

  # this one does not
  #.c2 configure -state [expr $cb(c1) ? "disabled" : "normal"]
  #.c4 configure -state [expr $cb(c1)||$cb(c3) ? "disabled" : "normal"]
}

Ns::main_routine
```

I want to fix the following line in the above code

`.c2 configure -state [expr $cb(c1) ? "disabled" : "normal"]`

When I use the above line I get the following error:

`can't set "cb(c1)": invalid bareword "disabled" in expression "1? disabled : normal";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always put `{`braces`}` around expressions, as that stops double substitution, leaving the `"`quotes`"` to do their proper purpose. You also boost the security *and* speed of your code by doing that, and have done since at least Tcl 8.0 (over a decade ago); before that, performance reasons meant that many people omitted braces, but that was a truly terrible habit.

In short, don't use:

```
.c2 configure -state [expr  $cb(c1) ? "disabled" : "normal" ]
```

But rather use this:

```
.c2 configure -state [expr {$cb(c1) ? "disabled" : "normal"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try 
`.c2 configure -state [expr {$cb(c1) ? "disabled" : "normal"}]`

Comment: while this answer hints at the solution, it would be a much better answer (and possibly get more votes) if you explained _why_ your solution works.

Comment: You're right @Bryan Oakley. Will do that next time. It's explained nicely by Donal Fellows. It's to ensure that the latter part gets executed first before expr is applied to it.